# Purpose of sub-query

Tags: mysql

I am working on one maintenance project where I need to optimize the query. It  is very coplex query so I have divided into 5 parts.

There in one table "document" where fields are

```
document_id(PK)
doc_name
fk_product_id
issue_date
date_expiring
status
```

Query is

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS this.* , COUNT(this.document_id) as count_document_id,
FROM ( SELECT * from documents where status != 'D' order by date_expiring desc ) this
```

There are millions of records but above query return only  record. I don't understand what this query means/ what records will it return.

Comment: `COUNT()` performs hidden GROUP BY and treates the whole rowset as single group. So the output rowset contains one row.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down.

Starting with the **subquery**:

```
SELECT * FROM documents WHERE status != 'D' ORDER BY date_expiring desc
```

The resultset is a subset of your `documents` table.

Next, the main query's **FROM**:

```
FROM ( /* that subquery up there ^^^ */ ) this
```

This treats the resultset of the subquery *as a virtual table* and gives it `this` for a name.  MySQL's query optimizer is usually smart enough to avoid extra overhead with this sort of subquery pattern.

Next, we'll look at the **SELECT**:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
       this.* , 
       COUNT(this.document_id) as count_document_id
 FROM ...
```

`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is [deprecated and pointless](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) here, but it does no harm. It's deprecated because there are better ways to count rows. It's pointless because this query necessarily must return only one row; read on.

`COUNT(this.document_id) as count_document_id` counts all the rows coming from the subquery that contain a non-NULL document_id. But `document_id` is the primary key of the underlying table so it will never be null. Therefore `COUNT(*)` would work just as well.  And, by the way, it makes the subquery's `ORDER BY` clause entirely pointless.

Because there's an [aggregate function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) on the SELECT line and no GROUP BY clause, the query aggregates all the rows in the subquery and yields just one row.

`this.*` is just plain wrong in standard SQL. And it's meaningless in MySQL:  the single row you get back from this query contains the count: that's fine. But by specifying `this.*` you also get back the contents of *just one randomly chosen row* from the subquery.  This will break when you move to MySQL 8.0. [MySQL has a notorious nonstandard extension to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) that enables this sort of random thing.

I hope this helps. Taking over somebody's code can be loads of fun, eh?